# Change datatable font color in Shinydashboard with infoBox

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I am trying to insert a DT:dataTable to a Shinydashboard infoBox. But both of the table background and font colors are very light, which makes the font not easy to see. So I tried to change the table property following DT examples using formatStyle such as this

```
DT::renderDataTable(formatStyle(datatable(mtcars), columns = 1:4, color = "black") )
```

But it did not take an effect. The font and background colors are still the same light. I have little knowledge on JS, so is there way to work around?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't see anything because the normal color is black. Try green for example. Concerning visibility: Why don't you try `fontWeight = "bold"`?

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. Seems the infoBox CSS overwrites the data table style.

Comment: Then you failed giving a reproductible example. I will try reconstructing your problem later.

Comment: So, fun fact: Due to infoBox Css, the font is already black and already bold. You can still change every font style like normal, but the default settings are bold + black. If you have further evidence that your problem persists, I would like to see a reproductible example.

Comment: Thanks, my code is bit long, but if I have time, I will try to reproduce it in a simplified code.